# Retaining bad_lines identified by pandas in the output file instead of skipping those lines

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have to convert text files into csv's after processing the contents of the text file as pandas dataframe.

Below is the code i am using. out_txt is my input text file and out_csv is my output csv file.

```
            df = pd.read_csv(out_txt, sep='\s', header=None, on_bad_lines='warn', encoding = "ANSI")
            df = df.replace(r'[^\w\s]|_]/()|~"{}="', '', regex=True)                  
            df.to_csv(out_csv, header=None)
```

If "on_bad_lines = 'warn'" is not decalred the csv files are not created. But if i use this condition those bad lines are getting skipped (obviously) with the warning

`Skipping line 6: Expected 8 fields in line 7, saw 9. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.`

I would like to retain these bad lines in the csv. I have highlighted the bad lines detected in the below image (my input text file).

[image]

Below is the contents of the text file which is getting saved. In this content i would like to remove characters like #, &, (, ).

```
75062 220 8 6 110 220 250 <1
75063 260 5 2 584 878 950 <1
75064 810 <2 <2 456 598 3700 <1
75065 115 5 2 96 74 5000 <1
75066 976 <5 2 5 68 4200 <1
75067 22 210 4 348 140 4050 <1
75068 674 5 4 - 54 1130 3850 <1
75069 414 5 y) 446 6.6% 2350 <1
75070 458 <5 <2 548 82 3100 <1
75071 4050 <5 2 780 6430 3150 <1
75072 115 <7 <1 64 5.8% 4050 °#&4«x<i1
75073 456 <7 4 46 44 3900 <1
75074 376 <7 <2 348 3.8% 2150 <1
75075 378 <6 y) 30 40 2000 <1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split on `\s` later with [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) rather than [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

```
df = (
        pd.read_csv(out_txt, header=None, encoding='ANSI')
            .replace(r'[^\w\s]|_]/()|~"{}="', '', regex=True)
            .squeeze().str.split(expand=True)
     )
```

Another variant (skipping everything that comes *in-between* the numbers):

```
df = (
        pd.read_csv(out_txt, header=None, encoding='ANSI')
            [0].str.findall(r"\b(\d+)\b"))
               .str.split(expand=True)
     )
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

         0     1    2   3      4     5     6  7
0   375020  1060  115  38    440   350  7800  1
1   375021   920   80  26    310   290  5000  1
2   375022  1240  110  28    460   430  5900  1
3   375023   830  150  80    650   860  6200  1
4   375024   185  175  96    800  1020  2400  1
5   375025   680  370  88   1700  1220   172  1
6   375026   550  290  72   2250  1460   835  2
7   375027   390  120  60   1620  1240   158  1
8   375028   630  180  76    820  1360   180  1
9   375029   460  280  66    380   790  3600  1
10  375030   660  260  62  11180  1040   300  1
11  375031   530  200  84   1360  1060   555  1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. This is so useful. But i have to use on_bad_lines='warn'. Otherwise some files are being skipped without getting saved to csv. Moreover, replace function is not working. Any suggestion ?

Comment: With the approach I proposed, I don't think you'd stil need to use `on_bad_lines`. But there is something I don't understand, if you want to keep those bad lines, why are you using `.replace` ?

Comment: Without on_bad_lines, those lines are not getting saved in the out_csv.

.replace - I am converting tables from images using tesseract and opencv. While most of the time, all the numbers are correctly gets ocr'ed, at times due to the quality of the image - special characters are generated in the output. So, i thought using .replace will remove those unwanted characters which will makes things easier during qc.

Comment: The trick is when I changed the `sep` parameter of `read_csv` from `\s` to `,` (the default), the whole text is read in one signle column (including the bad lines). Try to run my code and you'll see that those (bad lines) not only are preserved but only reformatted to fit the csv format ;).

Comment: I added another approach and both will make sure to skip none value.

Comment: I have tried the another code you have provided. All the columns apart from index (1st column) are not getting saved in the output csv.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example **as text** ?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the text output.

Comment: It's hard to image your expected output from what you shared. Can you add it to your question in a readable format ?

Comment: Sorry mate for the late reply.

Actually, the texts i have embedded in the question is how the output is. Is it possible to add as a text file here ?